# out of range random number generation in C++ using tr1

Tags: c++, random, c++11, tr1, uniform

I am trying to generate number from a uniform distribution of real number in the range of [0, 1). But compiler is generating numbers which are out of [0, 1) range.

Here is the code:

```
int main(void) {
    // Solver solve;

    mt19937 mteng;
    mteng.seed(rdtsc());
    uniform_real<double> uniRealD;

    double randomNum;

    for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++){
        randomNum = uniRealD(mteng);

        if(randomNum<0.5)
            cout<<index<<" no. random number is: "<<randomNum<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"number generate is not in range"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any comments on what could be wrong with the code? I am using `rdtsc()` as seed.

Comment: What numbers _are_ you getting?

Comment: here are the numbers:

2.59366e+09,
2.34439e+09,
3.48634e+09,
3.36609e+09,
3.68728e+09,
1.83477e+09,
3.47004e+09,
1.14211e+09,
2.24305e+09,
1.05343e+09,

Comment: Which compiler/version are you using?

Comment: gcc 4.6.1
library is working fine its just that this generation is out of boud.

Comment: Do me a favor and change `uniform_real<double>` to `uniform_real_distribution<double>` and test again.

Comment: man! that works,

but I wonder why this happened in the first place! Initially I was using tr1/random and then I used the lib: random only. and changed the distribution class name to as you specified and voila!

There seems to be some problem with tr1/random lib. Any other reasons???

Comment: The `uniform_real_distribution` class is from the new standard. The other is from the older TR1. Maybe the gcc TR1 implementation has a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to get rid of your seed function, `rdtsc()`, make some includes, introduce a `using namespace std`, and change a 0.5 to 1.0, and change `uniform_real` to `uniform_real_distribution`, but after that, using libc++, I get:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    // Solver solve;

    mt19937 mteng;
    mteng.seed(0);
    uniform_real_distribution<double> uniRealD;

    double randomNum;

    for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++){
        randomNum = uniRealD(mteng);

        if(randomNum<1.0)
            cout<<index<<" no. random number is: "<<randomNum<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"number generate is not in range"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

0 no. random number is: 0.592845
1 no. random number is: 0.844266
2 no. random number is: 0.857946
3 no. random number is: 0.847252
4 no. random number is: 0.623564
5 no. random number is: 0.384382
6 no. random number is: 0.297535
7 no. random number is: 0.056713
8 no. random number is: 0.272656
9 no. random number is: 0.477665
```

Comment: yup, 
seed is okay. I'd even recommend you to use it. Almost Unique seed every time. as for error there is problem with the library as aforementioned.
Thank you.

Comment: @cHaTrU The two ways I like to get seeds are (verbose) `mt19937(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count())` or (short) `mt19937((std::random_device())())`

Comment: Why do you need to change `uniform_real` to `uniform_real_distribution` ?

Answer (score 2):

Your code shouldn't be doing that. Probably a bug in the implementation. What compiler and library versions? Try moving away from tr1 to C++11.

Comment: @cHaTrU Indeed that appears to fix it. On IDEOne's GCC 4.5.1, using TR1 produces the bug but changing to plain `std` gives correct results: http://ideone.com/EYKao

Comment: passed that flag and changed the library to random and distribution class name to `code`uniform_real_distribution<double> `code` and it worked!
Any reasons for this wierd behaviour by the lib???

Comment: @cHaTrU It's a bug. They have their own reasons :vP

Comment: @cHaTrU You should probably upvote and select this answer… Howard did not mention that TR1 was the problem.

Comment: man i'll upvote your answer as i have th eprivilege to do that! and as for marking the answer, all of us debugged the problem simultaneously and Howard just posted a full working copy of that.

Comment: TR1 is deprecated in favor of C++11. Also C++11 randomis rather different than TR1 random.  OTOH it would probably be a good idea to file a PR in Bugzilla.  TR1 should not fail this badly.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(randomNum<0.5)
        cout<<index<<" no. random number is: "<<randomNum<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"number generate is not in range"<<endl;
```

Change the `if` statement to `if(randomNum < 1.)`

Comment: but that wouldn't have any effect on the generated numbers, right?
did that and still the same.
I even tried with the range of uniform_real<double> uniRealD(0, 1) but even that doesn't has any effect.