# uniform_real_distribution giving me values out of range

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

I am running the following function, and it is giving me values outside of the range [low, high) using Visual Studio 2012 (the random number result I'm getting is higher than the highest value I gave - e.g. 1.8848149390180773 for a range of [0.0, 1.0)):

```
double GetRandomDoubleBetween(double low, double high)
{
    assert(low <= high);
    static std::random_device rd;
    static std::mt19937 rng(rd());
    static std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(low, high);
    double random = distribution(rng);
    assert(random >= low);
    assert(random < high);
    return random;
}
```

I have seen this documentation link (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution) and this SO question ([out of range random number generation in C++ using tr1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133832/out-of-range-random-number-generation-in-c-using-tr1)) and I am not really seeing what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Does the code trigger one of the assertions?

Comment: It could be as simple as the usual problems with floating point comparisons.

Comment: @juanchopanza He gives a value of 1.8848149390180773 for a range of [0.0, 1.0).  That's considerably larger than what could be attributed to the usual floating point problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define your distribution:

```
static std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(low, high);
```

Note the `static`. That means that `distribution` gets constructed on the first call of `GetRandomDoubleBetween()` with the `low` and `high` passed then. The next time `GetRandomDoubleBetween()` `distribution` is *not* constructed again.

If you call `GetRandomDoubleBetween()` with different parameters then the second call will use the `low` and `high` from the first call. If you want to support different arguments then remove the `static`.

Also note that your design is not thread safe.